# Running pod install through plink gives sh:1: command not found: pod

Tags: ssh, plink

I want to run pod install on macOS 12.4 remotely from a windows 11 machine.

Im currently using (**option 1**)

```
plink -ssh -v 192.168.101.129 -l user1 -pw pw1 "pod install"
```

However, this gives

```
sh:1: command not found: pod
```

If I run pod install manually in the shell it works (**option 2**)

```
plink -ssh -v 192.168.101.129 -l user1 -pw pw1
pod install
```

**How can I run pod install remotely using the first option?**

Comment: On the remote system, what directory is the "pod" command installed in? And how is that directory added to your command path?

Comment: This led me to the answer @Kenster :) when logged into the remote machine through the GUI, the path was `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, and when logged in through plink it was `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. I added `/usr/local/bin` to the path by running the command like so: `plink -ssh -v 192.168.101.129 -l chris -pw cha29gall "export PATH=""/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" && pod install"`, which worked! Since you led me there, if you like, you can make an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)